# mysqli_real_escape_string converts the string but not saved to database properly

Tags: php, security, mysqli

i have a php script having some inputs and applied `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function to filter ..which are shown below

```
     $owner      = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['owner']);
    $purpose     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['purpose']);
    $type        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['type']);
    $city        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['city']);
    $location    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['location']);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['description']);
    $price       = floatval($_POST['price']);
    $land_area   = floatval($_POST['area']);
    $bedrooms    = intval($_POST['bedrooms']);
    $bathrooms   = intval($_POST['bathrooms']);
    $expire      = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['expire']);
```

and below is the insert query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO add_property SET owner='".$owner."',purpose='".$purpose."', property_type='".$type."',city='".$city."',location='".$location."',description='".$description."',price='".$price."',land_area='".$land_area."',bedrooms='".$bedrooms."',bathrooms='".$bathrooms."',property_expire='".$expire."',image_url='".$targetfile."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

**Problem**
it converts the string and add a slach if (  ' )etc if found like for 'abc it converts it to \'abc but not saved to database ...
**it saved to DB as is like ..'abc**

Comment: this is not an issue. when you fetch the row you should use stripslashes($content) to remove slashes.

Comment: It's not supposed to be stored escaped, but as string literal. Escaping is just meant to form a valid SQL query. And no @ErFaiyazAlam, you typically don't use stripslashes after fetching either.

Comment: @mario. thanks for correcting us.

Answer (score 1):

It will escape the string to keep it a valid SQL query, not to store the escaped version in your database.